# Excel -- inserting multiple rows at once

Tags: microsoft-excel

Anybody know how to insert multiple blank rows in Excel all at once?  Right now I right-click->Insert but that does just one row.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To insert 10 rows:

Select 10 rows and press [CTRL][+]

*also*

To delete rows select them and press [CTRL][-]

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:  highlight multiple rows and then when you do right-click->Insert, it will insert as many new blank rows as you've highlighted.